# React Navigation how to setup children routes

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I have a React Native Expo application using React Navigation. I think I have all the navigation routes (links) not well setted up.

So in my app let's say I have a Profile screen which has 2 list items to navigate. Application settings & User settings. These two have some more items inside each one.

My navigation tree would be something like:

- ProfileScreen (screen with 2 items => User settings | Application settings)

  - UserSettings:

    - Language (Navigation to LanguageScreen)
    - Change password (Navigation to ChangePasswordScreen)
    - Personal data (Navigation to PersonalDataScreen)
  - ApplicationSettings:
    ...

[image]

My LinkingConfiguration is configured like:

```
profileStack = {
    initialRouteName: "profile",
    screens: {
        profile: "profile",
        userSettings: "profile/userSettings",
        language: "profile/userSettings/language",
        changePassword: "profile/userSettings/password",
        personalData: "profile/userSettings/personalData",
        applicationSettings: "profile/applicationSettings"
    }
}
```

`profileStack` is a navigation stack. The rest are screens.

I'm wondering how I need to setup well the tree, because if I deep link to *myApp.com/profile/userSettings/language*, if I go back, I go directly to the `initialRouteName` which is profile, and I guess this is because the tree is not well generated.

In angular router would be setted as

`profile: path: "...", children: [ userSettings: path: "...", children: [ {...}]]`

How does navigation tree have to be setted up correctly in my example? Maybe using many navigation stacks?

Can anybody enlight me?

FYI:

- React Navigation: v6 (it was also happenning in v5)
- React Native: v0.69.5
- Expo: v46.0.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Navigation allows you to set up the same hierarchy you showed in your example. You want to nest the navigators just as in your depiction.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators

Something like:

```js
function Profile() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="UserSettings" component={UserSettings} />
      <Stack.Screen name="ApplicationSettings" component={ApplicationSettings} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function UserSettings() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Language" component={Language} />
      <Stack.Screen name="ChangePassword" component={ChangePassword} />
      <Stack.Screen name="PersonalData" component={PersonalData} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Profile />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

The structure of navigation is created by how you nest components.

Comment: So if I understand your comment well, I basically need to use a Navigation Stack for the `UserSettings`. Right?

Comment: @EstebanChornet A navigator can come in a few different forms, like tabs, or stack. The type of navigator will determine how the screens can be navigated to, within it.

But, yes, you need to put your screens in navigators. You will be nesting navigators to get the intended effect.

If screen A contains B and C, then A is a navigator. If screen B contains screens D and E, then B is a navigator.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks a lot man. My app is completely wrong haha